# LabVIEW Measured Frequency of Simulated Digital Signal Too High

Tags: signal-processing, frequency, labview, digital

I'm trying to measure the frequency of a simulated digital signal per [SOLVED: measure frequency of digital random signal](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/measure-frequency-of-digital-random-signal/td-p/2934420?profile.language=en). I don't need an averaging window because my signal will be consistent and not random.

**CODE:**

This is my code, which is identical to the code from the solution, minus the averaging window:

[image: Digital Signal Frequency Code]

**QUESTION:**

My simulated signal is a 0-5 VDC square wave with a frequency of 100 Hz and a sampling rate of 1000 Hz. **Why is it outputting that my frequency is 125 Hz?** (NOTE: Regardless of what value I enter for frequency, I measure a higher value than the true value)

[image: Digital Signal Frequency Solution]

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid logic error on my end. I forgot to add `dt` to `Period` one last time before enqueuing onto the `Periods` queue.

`Periods` holds the length of time of each recorded half period of the signal (hence the divide by two at the end before outputting to the graph). In this example, the signal frequency was 100 Hz (period 0.01 sec), so every half cycle is 0.005 sec long. By not adding the last sampling period before enqueuing, I was saying every half cycle was 0.004 sec. This is why the frequency was 125 Hz ( 0.5 cycles / 0.004 sec = 125 Hz).

Therefore, since we should add `dt` to `Period` regardless of whether a zero-crossing has occurred, we fix the code by moving the addition from the `False` case of the select statement to before the select statement, and simply pass the queue and sum through the `False` case (see below).

**IF True:**
[image: IF True]

**IF False:**
[image: IF False]

**NOTE:**
One could use the **Express >> Signal Analysis >> Timing and Transitions** VI to measure frequency, but it wasn't working for me when I started out for some reason, and more importantly I wanted to learn how to program this myself.